# include spark package in Sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I need to include the below spark package in SBT build.sc file. Please help me with sbt syntax.Also let me know how to

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation
```

[image]

Comment: please update the question with your sbt file as well.

Comment: name := "Basic1"
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.1",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.1",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib-local" % "2.0.1"
  )

Comment: where did you get `spark-mllib-local` ? Did you see the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.2.0" % "provided"`

**Please add this dependency in your build.sc file**, and you could easily use it in you spark application, such as your way:

`import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation`

Comment: Hi , It Worked thanks. Could you please explain me how did you predict .org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.2.0" % "provided"

Comment: @sumangorantla hi，glad to see it! When you want to use a package that the original uber jar didn't include. You should check the repository

Comment: @sumangorantla later, you should add the specific dependency on you build file!

Comment: Also i am getting below error, I tried running in verbose mode no luck, Please help 
Command : spark-submit  --master  local[2] Basicp1-assembly-1.0.0.jar

Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/E:/ScalCode/Sbtp2/sbt/target/scala-2.11/Basicp1-assembly-1.0.0.jar